# Проброс портов через ip6tables (на IPv6 интерфейсах)

Tags: linux, iptables

Необходимо прокинуть локальный порт на IPv6 интерфейсе. Должно выйти нечто: [::localaddress]:7777 -> [::localaddress]:8888. Думал о socat и xinetd, но отказался от них в пользу ip6tables, т.к. необходимо прокидывать TCP и UDP трафик одновременно (возможно это реализуемо через упомянутые утилиты, но я в них не разобрался).
Нашел весьма симпатичный мануал [ссылка](https://losst.ru/probros-portov-iptables-v-linux) (и еще несколько таких же) по пробросу портов через iptables, единственное, все они про IPv4.
Например вот такой параметр меня смутил:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

т.к. в ipv6 такого нет (речь про файл /proc/sys/net/ipv6/ip_forward).

Прошу подсказать, как через ip6tables организовать локальный проброс (редирект) портов на IPv6 интерфейсе. Необходим проброс upd и tcp сразу.

Comment: т.к. на другой адрес переправлять ты пакеты не собираешься, то и ip_forward включать не обязательно (для справки, похоже он включается в `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/forwarding`)... скорей всего тебе должно хватить по одному правилу подмены адреса в `PREROUTING` и в `POSTROUTING`... но точный их вид я не назову, чтобы не соврать...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
socat TCP6-LISTEN:7777,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[localaddress]:8888
```

Не уверен,  что это рабочий вариант, но всегда же можно отредактировать ответ)

Comment: socat не работает с UDP и TCP одновременно, что необходимо в рамках моей задачи, поэтому вопрос конкретно про iptables :)